# Can GRANT USAGE to @user'%' for a specific column table work?

Tags: mysql, sql, admin

novice in mysql here .

I have a database created in mysql called 'productes' and 'productos' is one of the database tables.

Productos has the following columns :

```
  CREATE TABLE Productos
  (
   IdProducto           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NombreProducto       CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   IdProveedor          INT,
   IdCategoria          INT,
   PrecioUnidad         DECIMAL(20,4),
   UnidadesEnExistenci  SMALLINT,
   Suspendido           TINYINT,
   KEY (IdCategoria),
   KEY (IdCategoria),
   KEY (IdProveedor),
   KEY (NombreProducto),
   PRIMARY KEY (IdProducto),
   KEY (IdProveedor)
  );
```

What I tried to do as root user from the command line was the following  :

```
mysql>GRANT USAGE (PrecioUnidad) ON productes.productos TO pepe@'%' IDENTIFIED BY            
      'pepe';
```

(i.e deny all access to user 'pepe' from all the domain machines to the column 'PrecioUnidad' of the table productos )

And I got an error(ERROR 1064) saying that I have an error in my syntax .

I thought to grant privileges to the rest of the columns of the table and exclude the specific one to get the desired result  but I thought that maybe there is another way .

So my question is **this** : Can grant usage be applied for a specific column table and I'm just missing something here , or is there another way to disallow all privileges for only one column table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view with all columns but **PrecioUnidad** and then grant (allow) pepe access to that view.

```
CREATE VIEW pepes_productos AS
 SELECT 
  IdProducto,
  NombreProducto,
  IdProveedor,
  IdCategoria,
  UnidadesEnExistenci,
  Suspendido  
 FROM productos
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Mysql Manual

> Column Privileges
>
> Column privileges apply to single columns in a given table. Each
>   privilege to be granted at the column level must be followed by the
>   column or columns, enclosed within parentheses.
>
> GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1,col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO
>   'someuser'@'somehost'; The permissible priv_type values for a column
>   (that is, when you use a column_list clause) are INSERT, SELECT, and
>   UPDATE.
>
> MySQL stores column privileges in the mysql.columns_priv table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges